# Change the language of date display

Tags: indicator, gnome-terminal, date

I recently installed 14.04, and my date/time display is unnecessarily localized. Upon installation, I chose Colombo as my location:

[image: location]

Now the date/time is displayed in localized form (Sinhala language). I don't remember choosing a language any other than English (US).

[image: top panel] 
[image]

How do I revert this to show date/time display in English (US)?

Edit: Executing `locale` on console produces following:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=si_LK
LC_TIME=si_LK
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=si_LK
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=si_LK
LC_NAME=si_LK
LC_ADDRESS=si_LK
LC_TELEPHONE=si_LK
LC_MEASUREMENT=si_LK
LC_IDENTIFICATION=si_LK
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Type `locale` to see what is set by default.

Comment: @Gnouc: I can see that several LC_* variables are set to `si_LK`. Added info to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to System settings and select Language Support app then do the steps like in screen shot:

[image]

Then restart the system for the change to take effect.

Comment: Thanks, this works, but **restart is required**.

Answer (score 1):

`LC_TIME=si_LK` affects your time output. Try:

```
LC_TIME=en_us ls -l
```

To make permanent changes, edit your `/etc/default/locale`.